# Does aniline react with FeBr₃?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, amines

I have read that aniline does not undergo Friedel–Crafts reaction because it complexes with Lewis acid $\ce{AlCl3}.$ Will it also react with $\ce{FeBr3}$ during bromination (to receive a 3-bromo substituted benzene)?

Comment: I was just about to ask a similar question as to why phenol doesn't react with Alcl3 and shows F.C reactions whereas o-cresol reacts with Alcl3(just like aniline) and doesn't show F.C reactions

Comment: Have you tried reacting the aniline with acetyl chloride or acetic anhydride first?  Conversion to an acetamide is one way to get avoid acid-base side reactions when doing EAS on an aromatic amine.

Comment: Oscar Lanzi - its a theoretical question, i do not do these reactions

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87145/why-doesn-t-aniline-undergo-friedel-crafts-alkylation